# How I define Fake Host in iis?

Tags: iis, asp.net-mvc-5

> This Is my Host file

```
192.168.1.15:33693 stackoverflow.com
192.168.1.15 stackoverflow.com
```

first line i get nothing
second line i get iis page

i want to get my site buy it does not working

> this is my applicationhost.config File

```
<site name="stackoverflow" id="14">
                <application path="/" applicationPool="Clr4IntegratedAppPool">
                    <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="C:\Users\stackoverflow\Desktop\stackoverflow\stackoverflow" />
                </application>
                <bindings>
                    <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:33693:localhost" />
                  <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:33693:192.168.1.15" />
                </bindings>
            </site>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the IIS manager, define a binding like so:

[image]

Equivalently, you can add the following binding statement in `applicationhost.config`:

`<binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:80:stackoverflow.com" />`

Additionally, `192.168.1.15` needs to be the IP of your machine. Using `127.0.0.1` is usually a better option to use in the host file in case your IP is assigned by DHCP.